# Symfony 4 - Checkbox not in request, when not clicked (added via js ad prototype)

Tags: forms, checkbox, twig, prototype, symfony4

I'm trying to use checkboxes as a Collection.
My problem is that some checkboxes are not sent in the request if not clicked: Those that are added dynamically via js.

For the purpose of simplicity, I created a test form where the problem occurs.

So, I'm using a Form with a CheckboxType Collection, with one predefined Item (unchecked):

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class TestType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'testcheckbox', 
                CollectionType::class, array(
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'prototype' => true,
                    'entry_type' => CheckboxType::class,
                    'entry_options' => array(
                        'required' => false,
                    ),
                    'data' => array(
                        1 => false
                    )
                )
            )
            ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
        ]);
    }
}
```

I got this twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% import _self as formMacros %}

{% block content %}
    <h3>Testform</h3>
    <div id="form_container">
    {{ form_start(test_form) }}

    <div class="js-test-wrapper" data-prototype="{{formMacros.printTestRow(test_form.testcheckbox.vars.prototype, test_form.testcheckbox|length+1)|e('html_attr') }}" data-index="{{test_form.testcheckbox|length }}">
    {% for testField in test_form.testcheckbox %}
        {% set counter = ( counter | default(0) ) + 1 %}
        {% include 'test/test.testfield.html.twig' with {'testField': testField, 'number': counter} %}
        {{form_widget(testField)}}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <span id="button_add_testfield" onclick="add_testfield()">+ Add Testfield</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success">
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ form_end(test_form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% macro printTestRow(testField, number) %}
    {% include 'test/test.testfield.prototype.html.twig' with {'testField': testField} %}
{% endmacro %}
```

As you can see, the twig uses two different twigs to print the checkboxes.
One for the creation via twig (for the existing Collection Items).
And one for the creation of new items via js.

```
//test/test.testfield.html.twig
<div class="form-group row" id="testfield_{{number}}_formgroup">
    <div class="col-sm-8" id="testfield_{{number}}_label">Testfield {{number}}</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        {{ form_widget(testField) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">

    </div>
</div>
```

```
//test/test.testfield.prototype.html.twig
<div class="form-group row" id="testfield___name___formgroup">
    <div class="col-sm-8" id="testfield___name___label">Testfield __name__</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        {{ form_widget(testField) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">

    </div>
</div>
```

And at last, the js method which adds new Items to the collection:

```
function add_testfield(){
    var wrapper = $('.js-test-wrapper');
    var test_prototype = wrapper.data('prototype');
    var index = wrapper.data('index');
    var newField = test_prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index+1);    
    $('.js-test-wrapper').append(newField);
    wrapper.data('index', index + 1);
```

The html output for the checkboxes are correct. Only the id is increased.

Now the problem:
If I don't check any of the checkboxes, only the first checkbox exists in the request. The others are only sent, when checked.
I already know this behavior from plain php/html.

But in this case, I want to show the form again. But that leads to a error, when submitted checkboxes are missing.

Does anybody know, what exactly makes the first checkbox always exist and how I can apply that setting to the other dynamically created checkboxes?

Greetings and thank you

Comment: Isn't that usual form behaviour? About the last paragraphs: "something is missing" sounds like you want to explain further **what exactly** is missing, especially if you stat that "everything seems to work fine"

Comment: It may be the usual behavior in php, but the symphony form needs the fields to be there. At least, when you want to show the form again after the request has been sent. If the fields are not there, an error "Key "2" in object with ArrayAccess of class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist."  occurs. The the forms need to be there. And no, I don't want to explain further, what exactly is missing, because that's why I'm posting the question. I don't know, what exactly is missing. Maybe the added form fields are not registered correctly in the form. I was hoping, someone's got an idea

Comment: Well, usual behaviour in current browsers overrides PHP behaviour overrides Symfony behaviour: a checkbox that is not ticked is not submitted, period. From all that code where you state "everything seems to work fine", I cannot conclude what **exactly** is not working. And without you saying what does not work, it's close to impossible to provide help

Comment: Ok, I get your point, but how is it possible then, that the first Checkbox (that one that is created from the existing child entry - Child 1) does exactly what I want: That checkbox exists in the request array, no matter if it is checked or not. The value is false or true. And I'm sure, that if I add a normal (means not a CollectionType) Checkbox to my form, it also has that expected behaviour... so there has to be a difference between the two creation approaches of the checkbox. And I wanna know that difference. I'm gonna try it with a normal checkbox and check out the request behaviour.

Comment: Actually I already have a normal checkbox in my form. And this checkbox is always there, no matter if clicked or not. So it's not the normal php behavior. So there has to be a solution for this problem...

Comment: Please reduce the code to a minimal example that triggers the problem. And if that works for one checkbox, but not for the other, what have you tried to spot the difference? Do they use the same names, identifiers, something else? Are both present if both are checked?

Comment: Hi! I don't know where to reduce the code, because every details could be important. I'll try to set up another page with a similar problem. As for your other questions: Yes, they use the same names, etc. The html output is exactly the same with a higher id. And more important: Yes, if both are checked, both are present and the form works...And the only difference is the data... for the first child, the data is set to 1. I will try around with that

Comment: Ok, I created a test form and edited the post. The problem also occurs in the test form...